# Javascript getElementById in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

401 is the value I want to get in iframe..

```
<iframe id="meal" src="about:blank" name="re">
     <td id="calories3">401</td>      
</iframe>
```

Then I have this in .js file

```
    var iframe = document.getElementById('meal');
    var frameDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var test = frameDoc.getElementById('calories3');
    window.alert(test.value);
```

But it says "test" is undefined..

when i did typeof(test) in console it says "object"..

I don't know why my test is the whole "`<td id="calories3">401</td>` "

How can I get the number?

Comment: Is that even valid HTML?  I didn't think you could use an `<iframe>` tag like that.  Also, you can't have a `<td>` outside of a `<table>` (or, well a `<tr>`).  Finally `test.value` won't work because `<td>`'s don't have a `value` property (that's mostly for `<input>`s), you actually want `test.innerText` or `test.textContent`.

Comment: Can you show the *actual* HTML you have on your page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to access the innerHTML of the node, rather than the node itself. Try `window.alert(test.innerHTML)`.

See [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Answer (score 0):

Is the iframe content was under the same domain as your page? If the iframe content was from outside of your domain, you cannot access it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can directly stick a child node inside an iframe tag like that. You need to actually load the content into the iframe.

If you run `console.log(iframe.childNodes);` you'll see that it actually returns a text object instead of a td element.
If you run `console.log(test);` it prints out `null` in the console, and `typeof null` == object.